# Equivalent of "coal plant" for oil

Tags: phrase-request

How do you refer to a power generation station that derives its energy from burning oil, rather than coal?

I looked up "oil plant", on onelook.com, thinking that it'd also be used to mean a place where oil is refined, but instead I ended up on Wikipedia's page on [vegetable oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_Plant), indicating yet another meaning of "oil plant".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the conventional terms are "coal-fired power plant" and "oil-fired power plant". You can drop the "power", especially if the context is clear, and just say "coal-fired plant" and "oil-fired plant". See, e.g. http://www.power-technology.com/projects/shoaiba/.

Comment: "Coal plant" is definitely very rare usage, with "coal-fired" preferred. I think I've seen "oil-fueled" and "[natural] gas-fueled" as often as "oil-fired" and "gas-fired".